Short novel about a man with a giant maggot in his house
Can someone please help me find a book I read at high school in the early 90s about a man who ends up with a giant maggot in his house that basically consumes his life. He stops looking after himself just to keep going out to find food for this thing. He eventually burns the house down when the maggot hatches. It's driving me mad as the net is of no use! I'm fairly sure it was called 'Maggot' but it may have been 'The Blowfly' and it was one of those 100 page quick read things.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You describe this as a short book, but you've tagged it as a short story.  Is it bundled with other works in the book, or is it just a single story?

I see some similarities to the short story "Food", by Thomas Tessier, in which a man frets over his neighbor, who's gaining an alarming amount of weight. She refuses to seek medical help. Her weight grows to exceed six hundred pounds while the protagonist brings her food and tries to convince her to address her health problem. She then turns into a giant worm, and the story ends with a hint that the worm ate the man. I read this in the 1988 anthology "Prime Evil", edited by Douglas E. Winter.

This was definitely a short book. I seem to remember a fly photograph on the front cover with almost human eyes.
It sounds quite similar to 'Food' but it wasn't that. The man ends up buying a side of beef for this maggot and eventually it hatches in his house. He sets fire to the house and can see it on its back through the window flailing as the fire takes hold.
